# I am getting XMLHttpRequest Error when I am trying to connect to parse server from flutter web app

Tags: xmlhttprequest, parse-server

I am getting XMLHttpRequest error whenever I am trying to connect to parse server through the flutter web app. I found it to be CORS issue but don't know how to solve this. I did see the documentation of parse_server_sdk_flutter where it says for web support, "Due to Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) restrictions, this requires adding X-Parse-Installation-Id as an allowed header to parse-server. When running via express, set ParseServerOptions allowHeaders: ['X-Parse-Installation-Id']" I have been looking everywhere to know where do I need to add this and how do I add this. Honestly, I don't know how to add this and which part of code to add this. I am stuck at this since couple of days. My whole project is based on this parse-server backend and I really don't know how to solve this issue. Please help!

Comment: Could you share more details on how you are running parse server?

Comment: I am running parse server locally using these commands in the documentation:

$ npm install -g parse-server mongodb-runner
$ parse-server --appId APPLICATION_ID --masterKey MASTER_KEY --databaseURI mongodb://localhost/test

Comment: If you spin up a dashboard connecting to this Parse Server instance, is it working well? Could you please also share the code that you are using to initialize the Flutter sdk?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ParseDioClient`:

https://pub.dev/packages/parse_server_sdk_flutter

```
await Parse().initialize(
  clientCreator: ({
    bool? sendSessionId,
    SecurityContext? securityContext
  }) => ParseDioClient(
    sendSessionId: sendSessionId,
    securityContext: securityContext
  ),
);
```